# What is the significance of -n parameter passed to sed command?

Tags: sed

Can someone please tell me how does  `sed -n '1!p` work ? Below is the full command which I am using to sort my pods in k8s based on nodes they are assigned.

```
kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces|sort -k8 -r| sed -n '1!p'
```

The above command works perfectly and the `sed` part removes the first header line from the final output.

I want to understand how does the sed part work and what's the significance of the parameters passed to `sed`?

Comment: What does sed's documentation say about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `info sed`:

`-n`:
By default, 'sed' prints out the pattern space at the end of each
     cycle through the script (*note How 'sed' works: Execution Cycle.).
     These options disable this automatic printing, and 'sed' only
     produces output when explicitly told to via the 'p' command.

`1p`: print first line

`1!p`: do not print first line.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `sed` will output every line it parses.
`-n` option is there to hide this output, and display only the lines specified with the `p` option.

In your exemple, `sed -n '1!p'` means "Display every line but first".

---

A more understandable example is when you want to search/replace with `sed`. If you want to see the whole resulting file you'll use this:

```
sed 's/from/to/g' file.txt
```

But if you only want to see which lines have been changed, use this:

```
sed -n 's/from/to/gp' file.txt
```